# IPCONFIG /registerdns on Windows increases Download Speed momentarily

Tags: download, speed, ipconfig

I'm downloading a large video file, and it is downloading somewhere in the rage of 50-75 KB/s.  I wanted to try and speed up the process, so - not really expecting anything - I flushed the dns cache and then executed `ipconfig /registerdns`.

For about 3-5s following pressing the enter key, the download speed (at least according to Chrome's download page) leaped up to 135 KB/s.  That's right around a 200% increase!

Then after a couple of seconds, back to normal.  Until...i executed `ipconfig /registerdns` again, and the results were identical.

Why is this?  I'm inclined to just execute something like:

```
    for /l %i in (1,1,10000) do `ipconfig /registerdns` & sleep 1
```

Have I tapped into something, or is there more to this than meets the eye?  And why?  I can't think of any logical reason for such a brief burst unless something is regulating downloads speeds that temporarily gets interrupted during dns server registration.

Comment: Why not simply test it by running the command above?  (though if it increases the speed for 5 seconds, perhaps 5 seconds would be a better delay).  My gut says that you're seeing a programming artifact (e.g. a counter or timer is reset, skewing the rate being calculated), so you should keep track of the start and end time and amount transferred to double-check the displayed rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or it could be the fact that during dns register, chrome's download meter counter is reset

When you start a download, the dns service is called to map the address to the download server.

Subsequent packets of data (the downloading file) do not have any dependencies on the dns.

Even unlimited connections are limited in some way, each node on a network has a limit threshold that several users combine to meet. Else the internet will be cluttered and slow, with sharp lag spikes during peak times. It is possible that calling a dns refresh messes with the limiter, but it doesn't make any sense.

End recommendation, try this again but use win network manager as the monitor.

Comment: That's it.  Doh!